# when I go to another page and come back to it, the INSTALL button disappears

Tags: ionic4, progressive-web-apps

Ionic 4, PWA. 
the **INSTALL** button to install the application

when launching the application, the **INSTALL** button is there. 
if I go to another page and go back to the first page, the **INSTALL** button disappears definitively.

note: if I refresh the navigator(F5), the button **INSTALL** appears

ngs-config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

comp.html

```html
...
    <ion-buttons *ngIf="showInstallBtn" slot="primary">
     <ion-button (click)="showInstallBanner()">
      Install
     </ion-button>
   </ion-buttons>
...
```

Comment: Kindly edit your post and include the other code as part of it. Have you tried to debug your code using the developer console tool?

Answer (score 0):

comp.ts

```
...
  deferredPrompt: any;
  showInstallBtn: boolean = true;
  pwa_features: any;

  constructor(
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private lcs: LoginCommercialService
  ) {

    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
      console.log('beforeinstallprompt Event fired');
      // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
      e.preventDefault();
      // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
      this.deferredPrompt = e;
      this.showInstallBtn = true;
    });    
   }

  showInstallBanner() {
    if (this.deferredPrompt !== undefined && this.deferredPrompt !== null) {
      // Show the prompt
      this.deferredPrompt.prompt();
      // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
      this.deferredPrompt.userChoice
      .then((choiceResult) => {
        if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
          console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
        } else {
          console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
        }
        // We no longer need the prompt.  Clear it up.
        this.deferredPrompt = null;
      });
    }
  }
```